# Share folder and Python file between Docker images using Docker Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I would like different Docker projects for my closely related projects `server_1` and `server_2` to live in one folder that I can build/deploy simultaneously using Docker Compose.

Example project directory:

```
.
├── common_files
│   ├── grpc_pb2_grpc.py
│   ├── grpc_pb2.py
│   └── grpc.proto
├── docker-compose.yml
├── flaskui
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   └── flaskui.py
├── server_1
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   └── server_1.py
├── server_2
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   └── server_2.py
└── server_base.py
```

Two questions I am hoping have one common solution:

1. How can I make it so I only have the common dependency `common_files/` in only one place?
2. How can I use the common code `server_base.py` in both server projects?

I've tried importing using relative directories in my project Python scripts, like `from ..common_files import grpc_pb2`, but I get *ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package*.

I've considered using `read_only` volume mounting in `docker-compose.yml`, but that doesn't explain how to reference the `common_files` from within a project file like `flaskui/Dockerfile`.

Comment: You reference those files(mounted by volume) with directory in container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mount your local directory that contains the grpc files and `server_base.py` as a volume in your `server_1` and `server_2` containers. That way, there is a single source of truth (your local directory) and you can use them from both your containers.

You can add the `volumes` definition in your `docker-compose.yml` file for your containers. Here's a bare-bones compose file I created for your use-case:

```
version: "3"

services:
  server_1:
    image: tutum/hello-world
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    container_name: server_1
    volumes:
      - ./common_files:/common_files

  server_2:
    image: tutum/hello-world
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    container_name: server_2
    volumes:
      - ./common_files:/common_files
```

`common_files` is the folder in your local directory that has the `server_base.py` along with the grpc files which you want to mount as volumes to your containers which need to use them. These are called host volumes since you are mounting your local files from your host as volumes for your containers.

With this setup, when you `exec` into `server_1`, you can see that there's a `common_files` folder sitting in the `/` directory. Similarly for `server_2`.

You can `exec` into `server_1` using `docker-compose exec server_1 /bin/sh`

You can also read up more on the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) for Docker volumes.